# Flutter: Pageview builder : Activate and deactivate listeners effectively

Tags: flutter

I am creating an infinite list of pages with the help of Pageviewbuilder.

```
 body: PageStorage(
      bucket: bucket,
      child: PageView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),              
          controller: controller,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Page(index: index, controller: controller);
          }),
    ));
```

And the controller is set simply as :

```
 controller = PageController(
  viewportFraction: 1.0,
);
```

Listeners to fetch data for the page are attached/detached respectively in the initState() and dispose() of the above page widget:

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
print('Init State of Page ${widget.index} called..');
//--- Listener activate ---
```

}

```
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
//--- Listener Deactivate ---
```

}

**While this is working with no issues am having two observations:**

1. When the user makes a slightest scroll from Page-1 to Page-2 , the setState() of the Page-2 is called(causing the listeners to fetch data setup on that page) even before the next page comes into view and when the releases the scroll, the dispose() of Page-2 is scrolled.
2. The scroll direction is set as Vertical. However, when in Page-2, if the user attempts to scroll horizontal there is a slight jitter causing build initiation of Page-1.

**What I am intending to achieve:**

- Only when the scroll from Page-1 has gone past 50% of Page-1, the
  Page-2 init State to be called.
- The right way to activate and deactivate listeners on individual pages.

Any inputs would be highly helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: The scenario is for whenever a page comes into view, I would be adding listeners to stream input data and the same needs to be deactivated when the page goes out of view. Thanks.

Comment: listeners to stream input data?  what does it mean? what stream?

Comment: Sorry if the use case is not clear and to rephrase: I am using a pagebuilder to make infinite list of pages. Each page created is a stateful widget. when page-1 comes into the view, I will stream Item-1 from server and so is the case for page-2. I will listen to stream of input data on initState of each page and deactivate the listeners on dispose() which is called when the page is recycled by Flutter.

Comment: ok, then you have `PageView#onPageChanged` property for that, or it does not work?

Comment: Thank you, yes I was working with that option and the onchanged provides a callback at the builder level but am not sure how to cascade the changed index value I get from onchanged down to the widget to activate/deactivate listeners.

Comment: `onPageChanged` gets called with the index of the current page - just use it in your streaming code

Comment: Thank you @pskink. I figured around the way of passing the onChanged value down to the widget with the help of Page storage bucket+key. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score -1):

To listen for page changes on PageView, you can utilize `PageView.onPageChanged(int)` - this is called whenever the page displayed in the viewport changes as mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView/onPageChanged.html).

```dart
PageView.builder(
  onPageChanged: (int page){
    // Do something
  },
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),              
  controller: controller,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Page(index: index, controller: controller);
  },
),
```